# Creating half silhouettes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

In a recent music video I saw an effect which I found quite awesome. I tried creating it myself in Photoshop but since I'm quite inexperienced with the software I wouldn't know where to start.

#### What I would like to do

I have a photo of a person taken in front of a greenscreen. I would like to give it a darkish cloudy or foggy background. I would make a silhouette in the front. But I don't want the complete person to be a silhouette. I want the right to light up like a light is falling on it. So that about 15% of the right side of the person is visible.

I don't know how to better explain this but I hope you know what I mean.

#### Example

[image: Example]

I mean something like the above example but with the shadow being a bit larger.

Comment: could you provide a screenshot, a similar image, something that could give a better reference? Or perhaps the name of the music video you watched?

Comment: @Luciano I have edited my question

Comment: You didn't pick the easiest thing to do. You pretty much have to paint in the shadows, so that it looks realistic, if that is the look you're going for. It kinda sounds like you're not going for photorealism?

Comment: And you'd have to start from a pretty decent picture. Preferably one that's side-lit. Because if you're gonna have to paint shadows *and* highlights, you're in for a treat.